# Android Swipe gesture not working

Tags: android, swipe, gesture, galaxy

In my app, **the code for swipe gesture works fine on the emulator**. But same code crashes when I test it on the Physical device(Galaxy tab). I am sharing some code and the log cat results. Any help is appreciated.

This is the class in my activity which implements the swipe.

```
    package com.example.testflashfile;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import com.example.testflashfile.GlobalVariables;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    Button nextButton;
    Button playButton;
    Button backButton;
    Context contextObject;
    GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ReadText readText=new ReadText(this);
        TextView helloTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displaytext);

        String fileName="textone";
        helloTxt.setText(readText.readTxt(fileName));

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this.getApplicationContext(),new MyGestureDetector());
        View mainview = (View) findViewById(R.id.mainView);

        // Set the touch listener for the main view to be our custom gesture listener
        mainview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        playButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent startAnimation=new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlayAnimationActivity.class);
                startAnimation.putExtra("SWF_NAME","a");
                startActivity(startAnimation);
            }
        });



        nextButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        backButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FifthActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener
    {


        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {


            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > GlobalVariables.SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
                return false;
            }

            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > GlobalVariables.SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > GlobalVariables.SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                //  left to right  swipe
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > GlobalVariables.SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > GlobalVariables.SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {


                Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,FifthActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }



    }

}
```

The log cat result is:

```
03-15 11:25:39.369: D/OpenGLRenderer(10179): Enabling debug mode 0
03-15 11:25:42.611: E/InputEventReceiver(10179): Exception dispatching input event.
03-15 11:25:42.611: D/AndroidRuntime(10179): Shutting down VM
03-15 11:25:42.611: W/dalvikvm(10179): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419442a0)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.MotionEvent.getY(MotionEvent.java:2090)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.widget.ScrollView.onTouchEvent(ScrollView.java:848)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7340)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2181)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1914)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2187)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1929)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2187)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1929)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2187)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1929)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2187)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1929)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2113)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1466)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2468)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2061)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7525)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3370)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3302)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4394)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4372)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4476)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:163)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4444)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4495)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:523)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
03-15 11:25:42.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10179):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It is not the problem of swipe gesture, instead in your MainActivity, file name you are trying to read returns null

Comment: @Pragnani I dont get it. How does it work on the emulator then?

Comment: Try to understand what I am saying, You can test the swipe on your emulator. But the problem is not with the swipe instead you got FileNotFoundException. Because you are trying  to read text file and the file name of text is null

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Pragnani . Please not the changes on my post. How can i fix it? I am not getting how come it shows filenotfoundexception.

Comment: @Pragnani I am trying to tell you that. The text files that i want to display are getting displayed on the emulator as well as the physical device. i have implemented next and back buttons on every such activity which has its own text file. When i am testing the app on the device and press on next the next activity is displayed without crashing the app. So what i am trying to tell you is that the swipe is not working somehow. the minute i swipe the screen the application crashes. When i swipe on the emulator it works just fine. Thats my problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26238/discussion-between-pragnani-and-abhi-is-learning-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mainview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

**this is the correct way of doing it. It works on the device now.**  But I still don't understand how was it working on the emulator.if any one can figure that out then please tell me. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing null as a input to the   `readTxt(null);` in your Read class, instead send the file name in the constructor and pass the file name to readTxt in that or **remove readTxt(null)  in your Read class**

Comment: My textone file which is the one that I want to display is getting displayed on the textview inspite of filenotfoundexception. how can that be?

Comment: Because you are calling   helloTxt.setText(readText.readTxt(fileName)); after instatiating your Read class

Comment: @abhi_is_learning_android but readTxt(null) is calling when you instantiate it first

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here

```
  public class ReadText {
    Context context;
    public ReadText(Context c) {
        context = c;
        readTxt(null);
    }
```

null is a keyword in java.. so u need to change the filename first which is there your assts folder(null.txt), after that using that filename in your code...